Doing something vs Going to do something
Could someone explain to me the differences between the following sentences?
I'm going to a party tomorrow
vs
I'm going to go to a party tomorrow.

For this native speaker of American English, the two have exactly the same meaning and usage. Well… perhaps the latter puts an ever so slightly heavier emphasis on the futurity (futureness?) of the speaker’s planned attending of the party.

The two examples are completely different uses of the verb go. Perhaps you should be asking about the difference between I'm going to work tomorrow and I'm working tomorrow.

I'm a huge fan of American English, Thank you for commenting @Paul Tanenbaum

Thank you @FumbleFingers as well for commenting

You have chosen a bad example.
"Going to do" is one way of talking about future events.  It is often used when we think of the present as leading to the events in the future, as in "plans made now leading to future events"
We can sometimes use present tense to talk about events in the future, when those events are fixed by timetable or calender.

I'm going to work tomorrow (I have planned to work tomorrow, it is my intention to work)


I'm working tomorrow (because on my schedule I have to work on Monday)

But since "going to go" is repetitive, we tend to use "I'm going" to mean exactly the same as "I'm going to go".  So your two examples mean exactly the same.

This helped a lot, Thank you James for answering my question @James K

Yes. My comment about the two sentences that you did ask about in no way contradicts this answer and the comment by @FumbleFingers.

Thank you for commenting anyway @Paul Tanenbaum , This might be weird for you but I've always wanted to talk to an American, So thank you again

You’re welcome. I only wish your first American correspondent could have been a more worthy one.
